# Is it possible to make pods of a StatefulSet to run different app images in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-statefulset, kubernetes-deployment

I want to create a StatefulSet where I want my first pod(i.e. ordeal index-0)to behave as a router(routing-app) for the pods starting with ordeal index 1(serving-app).

I am new to Kubernetes StatefulSets, and still trying to figure out their usage in real world applications.Please let me know, if am trying out something that I should not do from the design perspective or should I try something else to accomplish my requirement. Thanks, J

Comment: Can you talk more about the use case? Why wouldn't the router be a separate deployment?

Comment: @johnharris85, it's that I do not want my serving apps to come up unless the routing app comes up. And, if the deployment of routing app gets fail then the deployment of serving apps should also not happen.

Comment: I'd probably architect the application so that it retries or handles failures of the associate parts gracefully rather than try and leverage these constraints into Kubernetes primitives.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two pods of same statefulsets running different images. It is possible to run two different images in one pod and it will be same for all the pods of your statefulset. You need to create two different `statefulsets` or your application which requires persistence as `statefulset` and other as `deployment`. Refer the documentation `https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#limitations` for more information.